# Spring - AWS (no spring boot): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity manager repository, set up as follows:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(datasource());
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties(dynamicConfiguration));
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"<my model package>"});
    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return em;
}
```

My entity class is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "model")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Model {

@Column(name = "serialNumber")
private String serialNumber;

@Column(name = "region")
private String region;

@Column(name = "created")
private Date created;

@Column(name = "updated")
private Date updated;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

}
```

My repository beans are like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ModelRepository extends JpaRepository<Model, Long>, ModelCustomRepository<Model, Long> {

}
```

My custom repository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ModelCustomRepository<E, L extends Number>{

List<Model> getModelsSkipUpdated();
}
```

My Custom repository implementation

```
public class ModelCustomRepositoryImpl implements ModelCustomRepository<Model, Long> {

@Autowired
private DynamicConfiguration dynamicConfiguration;

@Qualifier("entityManageFactory")
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public List<Model> getModelsForProvisioning() {
    Integer limit = dynamicConfiguration.getIntProperty("model.limit", 25).get();
    Query modelQuery = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM Model WHERE status = :status LIMIT :limit for update skip locked",
                    Model.class);
    modelQuery.setParameter("status", NOT_PROCESSED.name());
    modelQuery.setParameter("limit", limit);
    return modelQuery.getResultList();
}
}
```

I get the below error, I don't get why I am getting the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class <package>.Model
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:472)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:181)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:119)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
... 54 more
```

I do not use spring-boot since this is an AWS lambda. Is there a way to work around this? Hence no @EntityScan.

My model class is not in the same package as the entity manager factory bean generation class.

On a side note, if there's a way to get the skip locked query within the @Repository bean, please let me know that as well.

Comment: Which database implementation are you using? (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)? For the `Skip Locked`, MySQL does not support it, but you can actually configure it with other DBMS if you are using `Hibernate`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/locking/Locking.html#locking-LockMode. What you do is set `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` `LockMode` with `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` = 2.

As for the unmanaged exception, because you're not using Spring Boot, are you sure that you don't require a `persistence.xml` file describing your entities since you cannot use `@EntityScan`?

Comment: We're using Postgres DB. Yeah, I can do the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode thing.

With respect to persistence.xml, let me try it out and get back to you, might work. I wasn't sure it was necessary.

Comment: Since I had the packages to scan in creating entitymanager, I thought that should suffice. Am I wrong? @XaeroDegreaz

Comment: It's a good question to be honest -- I've never used any of this without using Spring Boot. I'm interested to learn myself (even though _I'd_ probably never actually encounter this use case).

Comment: I can't use spring-boot, since I have the context being created without spring-boot initializing it. Lambda starts and I have context initializers starting my spring context.

Comment: Sure, I understand your use case.

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz persistence xml did it, could you please add that as an answer? I can approve it, might help others.

Comment: I know that you've resolved this issue using the `persistence.xml`, but I'm also curious if you've tried putting `@EntityScan` on your repository interface. If that works, too, I will update my answer.

Comment: I was not able to add @EntityScan, since I don't have the spring boot libraries, my lambda would be too heavy weight if I use Spring boot, that was my last resort though if things didn't work.

Comment: Also, EntityScan is on configuration or application class correct? Not repository class.

Comment: You're probably right but I was just thinking off the top of my head. Glad you're up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comments on your question: Since you're unable to use `@EntityScan`, perhaps you need to provide a `persistence.xml` describing your entities.